# synchronisation of pages in address bar in a web application using jsf2

Tags: jsf-2, faces-config

I'm working in a jsf2 application and I have a problem with the page name displayed in the address bar. When I navigate to an other page I have in address bar the name of the previous page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're using POST instead of GET for page-to-page navigation and JSF defaults to submitting to the very same view with you're using `<h:form>`. Using POST for page-to-page navigation is in any case a very poor approach. It's not only not user friendly (it's not bookmarkable and confusing), but it's also not SEO friendly (searchbots don't follow `<form>` actions).

To solve this problem, you must stop using `<h:commandLink>` for page-to-page navigation. Use `<h:link>` instead.

```html
<h:link value="Go to next page" outcome="nextpage" />
```

This will just render a

```html
<a href="/contextpath/nextpage.xhtml">Go to next page</a>
```

Which is perfectly bookmarkable, user friendly and SEO friendly.

When you're navigating to a different page as result of a real POST form submit, I'd also replace that by returning `null` or `void` and just render the result/messages conditionally in the very same view. Or if the result is supposed to be bookmarkable (e.g. search results), you should use normal links or plain `<form>` instead of `<h:form>` and use `<f:viewParam>` in target view.

#### See also:

- [When should I use h:outputLink instead of h:commandLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink)

Answer (score 2):

This is happerning because, in JSF, when you are navigating to a new page the server is performing a forward to the new page. The browser is unaware of the forwarding and is displaying the old url. To make the server perform a redirect instead of forwarding, you have to either:

If you are using navigation rules, add a `<redirect/>` to each rule:

```
<navigation-rule>
   <from-view-id>/pages/from.xhtml</from-view-id>
      <navigation-case>
    <from-outcome>to</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/pages/to.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect/>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

If you are returning an outcome from a bean method, add a `?faces-redirect=true` to the outcome:

```
public String navigate() {
   return "/pages/to?faces-redirect=true";
}
```